# JAX-RS Rest API accept header with parameters issue, jersey

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I want to split different resources by custom accept header for example:

```
@Produces("application/vnd.test+json; version=1.0")
public method1...

@Produces("application/vnd.test+json; version=2.0")
public method2
```

which throws

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.|[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods...
>
> These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7d44a19

Did anyone got a working solution with this pattern?

Comment: Why not use `application/vnc.test.1+json`?

Comment: its legacy system.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bug in jersey library.

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3003